# Javascript function exclude tags

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to select all tags within the body but would like to exclude the video tag this is my code so far I am not sure how to achieve the exclude - any advice and examples would be very much appreciated...

Amended (full) code:

```
        function assets(){
        "use strict";
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(video)");
        elements.style.transition = "opacity 8s linear 0s";
        elements.style.opacity = 0.25;

        var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        elem.style.transition = "opacity 8s linear 0s";
        elem.style.opacity = 1.0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS has a [`:not` pseudoclass](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) that accepts simple selectors like tag selectors. So

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(video)");
```

*(The `*` in `*:not(...)` isn't really necessary.)*

Here's an example that selects everything that isn't a `div`:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(div)");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(e) {
  console.log("Matched element: " + e.tagName);
});
```

```html
<span>I'm a `span`</span>
<p>I'm a paragraph <strong>with a `strong` inside</strong></p>
<div>I'm a div</div>
<section>I'm a `section`
  <div>I'm a `div` inside the `section`</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! very helpful - much apprciated!

Comment: Please see code above both video and body fade to 0.25 how would I implement above so the video remains. Basically video fades up from 0 opacity eveything else fades down to 0.25

Comment: In vanilla javascript if possible for sake of consistency

Comment: @jedihamster: Questions on SO are not supposed to be moving targets. If you're having trouble changing the opacity of the elements found by `querySelectorAll`, that's an entirely different question. I suggest posting it separately (once you've done your research :-) ).

Answer (score -1):

This code work same as PHP strip tag function. [Strip function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp).check this out.
`strip_tags(as, '<select>');` 
Here `as` is a variable which contain your tag code. All the tag which are declared in second parameter will not be removed.

```js
function strip_tags(str,allow) {
// making sure the allow arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
            allow = (((allow || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join('');

            var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi;
            var commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
            return str.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
                return allow.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
            });
        }
        var str2 = strip_tags(as, '<select>');  
        console.log(str2);
```